# Como copiar una tabla de una BD a otra BD - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Tengo que realizar una copia de unas tablas de una BD a otra BD dentro de la misma instancia SQL SERVER. Estaba pensando en utilizar la utilidad Importar/Exportar pero tendría que recrear los índices nuevamente y crear las estadísticas en la tabla destino.

Alguien conoce un método que migre la tabla con los índices, estadísticas y todo lo demás?

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes generar un Script donde solo incluyas la tabla que quieres 
clic derecho sobre la base de datos-
tareas- 
generar scripct-
siguiente 
y te saldra una ventana parecida a esta dependiendo de la versión que utilices 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

eliges la tablas o tablas que desees importar le das siguiente  y saldra una pantalla como esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

clic en el boton de avanzadas y allí podrás seleccionar las caracteristicas que desees exportar de tu tabla  datos,trigers, restricciones etc  te  generara un archivo .sql o puedes guardarlo en el porta papeles luego deberás ejecutar las instrucciones en la  otra DB  y listo

Tal vez es una opción más laboriosa pero puede funcionar =)

Comment: Creo que es la forma mas completa de crear la tabla con los indices, lamentablemente no puedo incluir las estadisticas, pero no se puede tener todo en la vida. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

### **Manejo de tablas entre bases de datos distintas**

Para **duplicar** una tabla, podemos hacer varias cosas:

1. Copiar sólo la ***estructura***:

   ```
   SELECT * Into <DestinationTableName> 
   From <SourceTableName> 
   Where 1 = 2
   ```
2. O bien hacer un ***duplicado*** exacto de la misma:

   ```
   SELECT * INTO <MyNewTable> 
   FROM <MyTable>
   ```

   con la salvedad de que, no se copiarán las *constraints* o índices.
3. Para enviar una tabla de una **BD_1** a **BD_2**, método ***cortar y pegar***:

   ```
   RENAME TABLE <bd_1.tabla> to <bd_2.tabla_copia>
   ```

   **Nota**: Elimina la tabla de la **BD_1**
4. Creará una tabla en la BD de destino y **almacenará** las tuplas de la tabla contenida en la BD origen:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE <BD_destino>.<nombre_tabla_copiada> 
   SELECT * FROM <BD_origen>.<tabla>
   ```

   **Nota**:  No elimina la tabla de la **BD de origen**
5. Creará una tabla en la BD de destino y copiará la **estructura** pero no almacenará las tuplas de la tabla contenida en la BD origen:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE <BD_destino>.<nombre_tabla_copiada> 
   LIKE <BD_origen>.<tabla>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `insert select` para copiar toda la estructura y datos de la tabla, así:

```
INSERT INTO tablanueva
SELECT * FROM tablaoriginal;
```

Por supuesto `tablanueva` y `tablaoriginal` no deben tener el mismo nombre si la vas a copiar dentro de la misma base de datos.

Puedes ver más información [acá](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp).

Comment: si tambien pense en eso pero mi duda es que si se copian tambien los indices y las estadisticas?? Gracias.

Comment: Los índices no los copia (no hay nada que lo haga) y no estoy seguro a qué te refieres con "las estadísticas".

Comment: las estadísticas son objetos que almacenan informacion de la metadata de las tablas, pero si me dices que no hay forma de copiar los indices entonces supongo que tampoco se podrán de las estadisticas. Mil Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con la herramienta de diseño de bases de datos  [MySQL WorkBench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) puedes exportar tu base de datos con las claves primarias y foráneas sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

entrando a la opcion de Generar Scripts para la base de datos y despues de seleccionar la tabla que quieres copiar, hay que entrar en el botón de Opciones Avanzadas y dentro de la lista aparece un item sobre que hacer con las estadisticas, por defecto no se hace script de las mismas, pero en la lista desplegable puedes seleccionarlo, te dejo una captura para que veas.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]